# Remove Na's From multiple variables in Data Frame at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

So I have a data frame: df and I plot it but there are too many Na's and it is not nice.

So I try to remove Na's with 1):

```
 df <- na.omit(df)
```

But my data are getting messed up. 2):

```
 df <- df[!is.na(df$column_name),]
```

This work for a specific column name but in the plot I have multiple column names with Na's and when I try to use the same command but for other column name it changes my data complitely. So can anyone help me? Is there a way to `!is.na`(Multiple column names) Or Ignore NA's In a ggplot?

I am using this:

```
df<-Ass1MatrixNoNa %>% gather(test, value, 3:5)
ggplot(df,aes(x=test,fill=value)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(preserve="single"))
```

[image]

And I get a plot but with NA's
Then I try to remove the NA's:

```
Ass1MatrixNoNa <- Ass1Matrix[!is.na(Ass1Matrix$Ass_1_hearingA),]
```

Removes the Ass_1_hearingA Na's But I want also hearingB but ovverides the first one and the NA's are removed only in the second one:

```
Ass1MatrixNoNa <- Ass1Matrix[!is.na(Ass1Matrix$Ass_1_hearingB]
```

Comment: Please post a little bit of sample data, show the code you are trying, and describe your desired outcome better. `ggplot` ignores `NA`s (does not plot them) by default, so it is not clear how your goal is different from the result you see. You will probably be helped if you read [some of the "How to ask" section in the Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How to make a reproducible example in R/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for great R-specific advice on asking questions.

Comment: I posted a sample code that I am trying to use and what I get

Comment: From the error that you mention below, you are using a data.table object, which can act differently from a data.frame object at times. It is important to include all of the information about your objects in your question. Please follow Gregor's advice above and produce a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for the code. We still cannot help without data. Please see the "How to make a reproducible example in R" link from my comment above, it will tell you how to add data to your question. We cannot help more until you share some data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if this is what you want. But if you are trying to deal with `warnings` from `geom_bar` regarding `NA`s, you may notice from the documentation (`help("geom_bar")`) that that the function has the argument `na.rm`. So the function can remove the `NA`s for you. Try

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=test,fill=value)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(preserve="single"), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Does that do what you want?

So you may not necessarily need to remove the NAs in `df`.

**EDIT**: 
Otherwise, the `complete.cases` function might help you:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 3, 4), value = c(1, 2, 3, 4), fill= c(1, 2, NA, 4))
print(df)
#   x value fill
#1  1     1    1
#2 NA     2    2
#3  3     3   NA
#4  4     4    4

ccol <- c("value", "fill") # Cols to keep 'complete'
df_complete <- df[complete.cases(df[, ccol]), ]
print(df_complete)
#   x value fill
#1  1     1    1
#2 NA     2    2
#4  4     4    4
```

Running `complete.cases(x)` returns a logical vector with `TRUE` where no `NA`s appear in the rows of `x`.

Alternatively, using the `tidyverse`/`dplyr`, something like the following

```
df_complete2 <- df %>% filter(!is.na(fill) & !is.na(value))
```

should do it too.

Comment: It is not clear how do you plot an '`NA`'? Can you try to save the plot you get and put in the question (just drag-and-drop)?

Comment: Complete cases wont work because it will remove the other columns value and I dont want that. I want to show it... in the plot

Comment: Then just subset the `df` inside `complete.cases` to only the columns you want to have complete cases for?

Comment: how? do I subset df` inside complete.cases?

Comment: I get this error:

Error: j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'ccol' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..ccol]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Comment: This is what I tried:

`ccol <- c("Ass_1_hearingE", "Ass_1_hearingC","Ass_1_hearingA") # Cols to keep 'complete'
Ass1MatrixNoNa <- Ass1MatrixNa[complete.cases(Ass1MatrixNa[, ccol]), ]
`

Comment: Well, unless you post some of your actual data, it is not easy to help you further. I just assumed your `df` is a standard `data.frame` or perhaps a `tibble`. But it appears it is not.

Comment: Can I contact you somehwere else? Because I cant start chat yet here...?

Comment: Well the data is as you see in the plot. I have Variables HearingA,HearingC,HearingE with values NA,not fullfilled, partly fulfilled and fulfilled. And I just have many NA's and want to show in the plot all the other values except the NA's and just cant do that...

Comment: Yes, I/we can sort of guess what data you have based on the code snippets and plot. But that tells us nothing about the precise structure of you data. I have showed you examples that work with common data structures. Please see the link on making a good minimal reproducible example given by Gregor in the other comments.